# SQL Error IBM DB2 with MERGE INTO and Prepared Statements

Tags: sql, db2, prepared-statement

I changed an SQL today from very unsafe way into prepared statements. So the two variable values were replaced by "?". But finally I get this error message:

**[IBM][CLI Driver][AS] SQL0584N The statement failed because of an invalid use of the NULL keyword or the DEFAULT keyword. SQLSTATE=42608 **

the SQL:

```
MERGE INTO MYTABLE A 
USING (VALUES (?, ?)) 
AS B(OID,NOTIZ)
ON (A.OID = B.OID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET NOTIZ = B.NOTIZ 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (OID,NOTIZ) VALUES (B.OID,B.NOTIZ);
```

this happens independet of the values and the type of values. For example I use 123 and "hello" or anything else. At the columns NULL is not allowed but I dont try to fill NULLs here.
This kind of changes work at 99,9% of my SQLs, just at MERGE INTO this problem occur.
It's independet of the client or programming language. It happens as well in DB VIsualizer or by JAVA.

Who has an idea?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes 100%, at DB Visualizer a popup asks for them (and type), not visible in screenshot

Comment: There is something about adding an explicit conversion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152474/how-to-upsert-row-into-db2-iseries-using-parameters-in-c-sharp-ado-net

Comment: Does it work with `USING (VALUES (cast(? as int), cast(? as varchar(100))))` ?